# How do I delete turtle pen lines in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I want to delete only turtle pen lines from a halfway point in a model run. The "clear-drawing" primitive seems to achieve that, but my problem is that I can't run it directly from an agent, or use "ask observer [clear-drawing]". Is there a way to trigger this observer command from an agent context (I expect not), or is there another way of erasing turtle pen lines? My solution to re-draw using pens having the background color is rubbish.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, but does this do what you want (in the go procedure) - `if ticks = 100 [ clear-drawing ]`? Or if you want to be able to do it manually, have a button with the command `clear-drawing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of redrawing using the background color, use `pen-erase`. If that's equally “rubbish”, perhaps you want something more like the answers here? [NetLogo turtles leaving a trail that fades with time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21074186/86485)

About `clear-drawing` being observer-only though, that seems like it shouldn't be too hard to work around, something like:

```
to go
  let clear? false
  ask turtles [
    ...
    if ... [
      set clear? true
    ]
    ...
  ]
  if clear? [ clear-drawing ]
  tick
end
```

Comment: This is a great technique for a lot of things in netlogo

Comment: thanks Seth, I had not thought of using a global Boolean to trigger an event in the go loop. Neat solution.