# Need Help Removing Traces Left By Turtles In "pen-down" Mode

Tags: netlogo, trace, pen

I created a turtle and added "pen-down" to see how the turtle traveled and once the turtle stopped, it was hard to spot its final location with all the traces. I need help removing traces left by turtles in "pen-down" mode in order to see the turtles final location. I'd like to do this by pressing a button on the interface that removes the traces, however, I don't know the exact code to be able to do that.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want `clear-drawing`, http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#clear-drawing.

But see also this similar question: [How do I delete turtle pen lines in netlogo?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34202240/86485)

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I was searching for.